# What is the correct method to link a homepage to multiple views in a django app

Tags: html, django, database, web, view

As the titles, I'm looking for the correct way to "link" views to a homepage, so whenever I press one of the buttons in the homepage, it will redirect me to a view related to a form.

Right now my django app is composed by multiple views where each one of them are forms that have their own .html but I'm having a hard time to understand or find a way to make a homepage where I have links to specific views and whenever I press the submit button inside the respective form, it would redirect me to the homepage.

I was thinking that the correct way to do it was making a new view that will take the role of my "homepage" but I don't know if its possible to have multiple views related to the same view

Note: I understand that coding an example for this would take a while, I am just making this question so I can get a better idea and start looking in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that I fully understand your question. However, hopefully the below information may help you get a better idea and start looking in the right direction.

##### redirect()

The `redirect()` function in Django can be used to redirect to another view/URL from within a view function.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect.

##### {% url %}

The `url` template function can be used to link to other views/web pages from within a Django template. This prevents the need to hard-code URLs into web pages.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you want to redirect to homepage after submitting a form.
[you can check this link how to add action in form](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_action.asp) though it's w3school tutorial in HTML form.

So, here I am adding code from django documentation.

```
<form action="/your-name/" method="post">
<label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
```

So, you can add action to homepage. just add the page URL name in the action tag ---
suppose you homepage URL is like below ---

```
path('index/', views.index, name='home'),
```

Then add home to the action place ---

```
<form action="{% url 'home' %}" method="post">
<label for="your_name">Your name: </label>
<input id="your_name" type="text" name="your_name" value="{{ current_name }}">
<input type="submit" value="OK">
```

That will work for sure.

**For more information** you can go through the below references ---

you will get this in django official documentation as well.
[check this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/)

And here is the whole forms documentation of django
[check this link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/)

Still if am wrong or didn't understand you question then please correct me.

Thanks for your question.